# how can I plot on the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I actually want to recreate an image like the following:
[image]

Specially the little X on the xaxes 
I have a

```
list = [[100,-3],[200,None],[120,-2] ... ]
```

and I do

```
for x in list:
     if x[1]!=None:
          plot(x[0],x[1],'ok')
     else:
          ###  PLot on the axes ###
```

But while I am plotting I do not know what the axes are. I know that some values are None, for example ( 250,None), So I want to plot on the xaxes at x = 250, but I have not idea what eventually the min(ylim()) will be.

I know I can do `plot(250,-5,'X',zorder=999999)` but this is only when I know what the min axes is..  (**I can not do min, max and so to know the min axes. as the real data is a list inside a list inside a dictionary etc..** )

Comment: Add code which you have tried

Comment: Are you asking how to plot over the axes spine (the x-axis line)? Or would you like to plot exactly onto the line (i.e. set the point onto the line instead of specifying a y coordinate)?

Comment: @hitzg yes I want to plot on the line, and not specify a y coordinate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the trick is to use a custom transformation. The regular data transformation for the x axis and the axes transformation for the y axis. Matplotlib calls that a blended transformation, which you need to create yourself. You'll find more information in this [awesome guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html).

And as @ThePredator already pointed out, you have to set `clip_on=False`, otherwise your markers will be clipped.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# the x coords of this transformation are data, and the
# y coord are axes
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory( ax.transData, ax.transAxes)

# data points on the axes
x = np.random.rand(5)*100. + 200.
y = [0]*5
ax.plot(x, y, 'kx', transform=trans, markersize=10, markeredgewidth=2,
        clip_on=False)

# regular data
x = np.random.rand(5)*100. + 200.
y = np.random.rand(5)*100. + 200.
ax.plot(x, y, 'ro')

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `clip_on = False` option. Example:

In your case, you can set your y limits.

Example:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

plt.plot(x,y,'x',markersize=20,clip_on=False,zorder=100)
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But this is only If I know the axes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`get_ylim()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim) in order to get the position of the axis and then plot on it.